# add fragment to backstack that is already inside it

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

What happen if a add to BackStack a fragment that is already inside it? 
For example:

```
Fragment one = new Fragment();
Fragment two = new Fragment();

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.viewGroup, one).addToBackStack(null).commit();
//...
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewGroup, two).addToBackStack(null).commit();
//...
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewGroup, one).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

When i add again fragment "one", two references to it is inside stack or only lastest is mantained ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even through the `instance of the fragment` is same, the `BackStack` entry will be increased, when an already exist `Fragment` is added to `BackStack` again.

When you add `First Fragment` , the back stack entry will be `one`.

When you replace `Second Fragment` ,the back stack entry will be `two`

When you replace `First Fragment` ( even though the same `First Fragment instance`),  The `older (first) Fragment instance` will be `reused`. but the `BackStack entry will be three`

Now the stack will look like this

```
`First Fragment` -> `Second Fragment` -> `First Fragment`
```

So when `Back pressed` `Fragments` will be popped out as `Fist Fragment , then Second Fragment and then again First Fragment`.

This is the `addBackStackState` method in `FragmentManager`

```
 void addBackStackState(BackStackRecord state) {
    if (mBackStack == null) {
        mBackStack = new ArrayList<BackStackRecord>();
    }
    mBackStack.add(state);
    reportBackStackChanged();
}
```

You can look at the `BackStackRecord` class to understand more how `addBackStackState` method is called.